# C++ Alloc Errors Adding Objects to Vector (or Deque or List) in an OpenMPI For Loop

Tags: c++, list, vector, openmpi, deque

I'm using C++ (written for Windows and Linux) compiled for OpenMPI.  I'm getting a strange series of allocation errors when adding a class object to a vector inside the OpenMPI for loop.  Debugging shows a shifting pattern of alloc errors, all centered around my "AddEntry()" method, but the errors never fall out in a consistent place in the loop or on a consistent member within the object I'm adding (therefore, I believe the object is not the problem, those details are not included in the question code).  I tried reserving space for the vector and I tried solutions using both deque and list.  I tried passing the object to the add member as an object, reference and pointer (instantiated with 'new ()') and none of these solutions resolved the issue.  This is my code:

```
#include "MyEntryClass.h"
#include "MyVectorClass.h"

#include <omp.h>

CMyVectorClass::CMyVectorClass()
{
    try
    {
        m_vEntries.clear();
        m_vEntries.reserve(750000);
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
        cout << "ERROR [CMyVectorClass] Exception Code:  " << ex.what() << "\n";
    }
}

//  Interface (public)

bool CMyVectorClass::AddEntry(CMyVectorClass_Entry& eAdd)
{
    try
    {
        m_vEntries.push_back(eAdd);

        return true;
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
        cout << "ERROR [AddEntry] Exception Code:  " << ex.what() << "\n";
    }

    return false;
}

bool CMyVectorClass::DoOMPLoop()
{
    //  Max processors for omp
    int nMaxProcs
    //  Continue, if true
    volatile bool vbContinue = true;
    //  Loop counter
    long lMaxCount = 100000;

    try
    {
        //  Iterate through files
        //  Declare team size
        #pragma omp parallel for shared(vbContinue) num_threads(nMaxProcs)
        for (long lCount = 0; lCount < lMaxCount; lCount++)
        {
            //  The entry object to add
            CMyEntryClass cAdd;

            //  Do some stuff to the entry
            cAdd.SetStuff();

            //  Catalog the data
            vbContinue = AddEntry(cAdd);
        }
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
        cout << "ERROR [DoOMPLoop] Exception Code:  " << ex.what() << "\n";
    }

    return false;
}

//  Implementation (private)
```

This problem has cost me many long hours of frustration attempting to resolve and none of the help I can find on StackOverflow (or the 'net at large) has enabled me to resolve the issue (though it has helped me optimize other code).  Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and tribulation, I realized the alloc errors were not the source of the problem (since my machine has beaucoup memory and the reserve limit was never even close to exceeded).  I began to suspect the AddEntry() method inside the OpenMPI for loop was inducing collisions.  So I used "resize" instead of "reserve" and I used an indexed "SetEntryAtIndex()" function to simply reset an object at a given place in the vector (note, this sort of random access is not allowed with all similar containers).  This is my code now:

```
#include "MyEntryClass.h"
#include "MyVectorClass.h"

#include <omp.h>

CMyVectorClass::CMyVectorClass()
{
    try
    {
        m_vEntries.clear();
        m_vEntries.resize(750000);
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
        cout << "ERROR [CMyVectorClass] Exception Code:  " << ex.what() << "\n";
    }
}

//  Interface (public)

bool CMyVectorClass::SetEntryAtIndex(CMyVectorClass_Entry& eSet, long lIndex)
{
    try
    {
        if ((lIndex >= 0) && (lIndex < m_vEntries.size()))
        {
            m_vEntries[lIndex] = eSet;

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            ReportTimeStamp("[SetEntryAtIndex]", "ERROR:  Index [" + ConvertLongToString(lIndex) + "] is Out of Range [0:" + ConvertLongToString(m_vEntries.size()) + "]");
        }
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
        cout << "ERROR [SetEntryAtIndex] Exception Code:  " << ex.what() << "\n";
    }

    return false;
}

bool CMyVectorClass::DoOMPLoop()
{
    //  Max processors for omp
    int nMaxProcs
    //  Continue, if true
    volatile bool vbContinue = true;
    //  Loop counter
    long lMaxCount = 100000;

    try
    {
        //  Iterate through files
        //  Declare team size
        #pragma omp parallel for shared(vbContinue) num_threads(nMaxProcs)
        for (long lCount = 0; lCount < lMaxCount; lCount++)
        {
            //  The entry object to add
            CMyEntryClass cAdd;

            //  Do some stuff to the entry
            cAdd.SetStuff();

            //  Catalog the data
            vbContinue = SetEntryAtIndex(cAdd, lCount);
        }
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
        cout << "ERROR [DoOMPLoop] Exception Code:  " << ex.what() << "\n";
    }

    return false;
}

//  Implementation (private)
```

The trick is resizing to create a fully (and even OVER) populated vector and then using an index to ensure there are no collisions inside the OpenMPI loop.

Comment: Instead of explicitly checking for the index out of bounds like that, all you needed to do was use `vector::at()` and  catch the `std::out_of_range` exception if there is a boundary issue.  `try { m_vEntries.at(lIndex) = eSet; return true;} catch(std::out_of_range& e) { error }`

Comment: This only ANOTHER solution to the problem.  The point is, a standard push_back operation won't work within a parallel loop.  The solution I provide accomplishes two things:  1) it avoids collisions, and 2) it pre-allocates the space needed for the vector.  Since I already have some idea of the size of the collection (code not shown, I'm passing a list of items to fill it), the use of the "resize(#)" syntax avoids costly re-allocations of the array (which, to my understanding, requires full-copies of the data set).  Catching an exception seems an inferior solution due to it being unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

I think there must be something else wrong with the first snippet. Perhaps you are corrupting the vector in code that is not shown?  The little snippet below does more or less the same thing and works fine.  Note that the loop slops past the end and the vector resizes itself.

```
#include <vector>

int main(int arg,char*arv[])
{

   std::vector <int> my_vec;

   my_vec.clear();
   my_vec.resize(750000);

   for(int i=0;i<760000;i++)
     my_vec.push_back(i);
   return 0;
}
```

--Matt

Comment: This code/suggestion does not address the issue.  The issue is vector (or deque or list) push_back in OpenMPI.  Your code is okay WITHOUT OpenMPI.  The collisions occur when the for loop is embedded in an OpenMPI for directive (NOTE the #pragma omp... directive in the code sample).  It's the multi-processor push_back that causes the collisions - in fact, it was a tough bug to catch because it would sometimes pop-up at the beginning, the end, on a string feature-set, on a long feature-set, or with no obvious failure at all.

Comment: I see.  Yes, the STL vector is not safe for multithreaded write access. 

Your second solution still concerns me and is probably engaging in undefined behavior.  For instance, the collision can still occur if the vector grows.  What will happen if two threads write to the same index concurrently and the element is complex?  At best that will be a race condition at worst it will corrupt the element

Does your solution -require- more than one thread writing into the Vector at the same time?  Or can you introduce a mutex on the write? A mutex solves the concurrency issues.

Comment: Use of the index COMBINED with the initial resize(#) syntax avoids both your concerns.  The resize() syntax (unlike reserve()) FILLS the vector with objects.  Since the OpenMP loop explicitly requires the counter to be declared and fully managed within its purview, there is ever only one index.  One index.  One item per index.  No need to resize again (code not shown, I'm passing a list of objects to fill the vector, so I know its size).  Mutexes are A solution, but a more complicated one (here I'm only using the addition of an index, which is the counter, no other object management required.)